# How to publish a lower version of a Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is it possible to publish a Ruby gem with a lower version than the latest?

For example, my gem version 1.0.0 requires `Ruby >= 2.5`. Version 2.0.0 requires `Ruby >= 2.6`.

Can I continue supporting Ruby 2.5 by publishing a bug fix to version 1.0.1?

Comment: Yes, you can. Why?

Comment: Almost exactly the reason I described in my example. I expect an upcoming version of a gem to raise the Ruby requirement, and I hoped to keep the option of patching earlier versions.

Comment: Take a look at Rails for example: both, [6.0.2.1](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2019/12/18/Rails-6-0-2-1-has-been-released/) and [5.2.4.1](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2019/12/18/Rails-5-2-4-1-has-been-released/) were released on December 18th, and both addressing CVE-2019-16782. It's quite common for popular gems to update / patch older versions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Just adjust the [`required_ruby_version`](https://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#required_ruby_version=) in your `.gemspec` file before uploading.

For example:

```
spec.required_ruby_version = '>= 2.5.0'
```